# Yii2 REST Calls crash when Controller name has caps

Tags: php, rest, yii2

For instance. I have one controller (auto generated by Giiant) called `CategoryEquipmentController`. I have prepared this controller to respond REST calls. with:

```
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\web\Response;
```

and

```
class CategoryEquipmentController extends ActiveController {
public $modelClass = 'app\models\CategoryEquipment'; ...
```

If I change its name to `Categoryequipment` on the file too it works fine.

Why does it throw an 404 on my hosting account since it works fine on my local?

Comment: Check that the filename's case has actually changed on your hosting account. I've run into this issue before where I changed a file name, committed it to git, pushed it live, and git's settings didn't acknowledge the change. Even if you don't use git, some other process may have prevented the change from occurring on your hosting account.

Comment: I had a typo, it works when I change file name to "CategoryequipmentController" if I left it as "CategoryEquipmentController" it just doesn't work. Willem, seems it is fine on the server.